# What is the definition of "Panim Chadashos" (new "face") with regard to Sheva Brachot?

Tags: halacha, wedding, sheva-brachos

Earlier this week I was at a friend's wedding, and I had to leave shortly after the Chupah. That made me wonder: with regards to saying all 7 of the blessings at a "Sheva Brachos" meal, we require a Panim Chadashos ('new face', someone who hasn't partaken in the wedding festivities with the new couple yet). However, how 'new' must the person be?

Possible permutations:

- If someone was at the Chupah, but no other part of the wedding (specifically that part, as Sheva Brachos are said under the Chupah too).
- Only there for the meal. By a Siyum I know that ([at least some opinions](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/57093/does-a-bchor-need-to-fast-if-he-didnt-partake-in-food-from-the-siyum)) hold that being at the meal alone is enough to be considered 'part of the Siyum'.
- You happen to meet the couple somewhere, something as simple as walking down the street. You wish them Mazal Tov (or not, maybe that would affect the rule) and keep walking along.

Comment: Very broad question, and based on a number of machlokos rishonim. In your case (leaving after the chuppah), Rambam holds that you may not serve as Panim Chadashos, but other rishonim do allow.

Answer (score 5):

[Nit'ei Gavriel](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46546&st=&pgnum=169&hilite=) addresses the first two items

There is a controversy regarding someone who attended the *Chuppah* and heard the *Sheva Brachot*. The ruling is to be lenient and consider him *panim chadashot*

Someone who stayed for the meal for a significant length of time is **not** *panim chadashot* regardless of whether he stayed for *Sheva Brachot* at the end or left early. Conversely, if he came at the end and heard *Sheva Brachot* but never ate the meal, he is also not considered *panim chadashot*.

The last item doesn't seem to be mentioned. But inferring from the pattern that *Nitei Gavriel* establishes that hearing *Sheva Brachot* is what disqualifies being *panim chadashot*, it seems that in your third case, you **would** be considered as *panim chadashot*.